# How to set Finder to always use Column View?

Tags: finder

How do I set Finder to always use Column view for all folders? There is no "Use as Default" for this particular view. And is there a way to automatically set the columns to be of equal width (instead of resizing manually)?

I'm using Catalina 10.15.7.

[image]  [image]

<sup>Click for full size</sup>

Comment: I don't think you can set column view as a default option without potentially changing the finder plist manually yourself in terminal. As to how you can do this, I'm not sure but it would involve a defaults write command. The plist is located at `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist`. This is also the plist to set your preferred widths, again utilising a default writes command. Hope that helps